# Shisha Vetish'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred ninety-six?

### ?ששה ותשעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 296.

Don't run after lazy gematria unless it's rock-solid.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred ninety-five entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timeline of the leaders of Chassidus and then of Chabad (beginning with the Baal Shem Tov and ending with the seventh Lubavitcher Rebbe - an example is [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/157178/jewish/Founders-of-Chassidism-and-Leaders-of-Chabad.htm)) spans 296 years, from the Baal Shem Tov's birth in 5458 (1698) to the seventh Rebbe's passing in 5754 (1994).

Answer (score 2):

> According to the statistics of 1898 there were 296 [Jewish colonies [in Russia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_of_Settlement) (apart from those in Poland), comprising 305,407 acres.

—Israel Cohen, [*Jewish Life in Modern Times*](http://books.google.com/books?id=M14-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA197&dq=296)